# Salesforce community login flow while using OKTA authentication is not complete in Mobile Publisher Playground resulting into links not working

Tags: salesforce, okta, salesforce-communities, sfdc

I have created a custom login page for a salesforce community and I am using OKTA authentication for that. **I am using mobile publisher playground.** So once I put all the credentials, It logs me into the community successfully but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbNGl.jpg) shows at the top the app as if the login flow is not complete. Another reason I think like that because [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcua4.jpg) permission is not asked.

Due to this Links in playground app are not opening at all (At least I think the reason for this is not completing login flow). Is there any fix or is there any possible reason for this issue?

I tried to look into **Login History** in Setup. It shows that Login is **Successful**.